# Css on razor page does not work locally but on server it does

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I used .net 6 with razor pages to create an application. I wanted to add some css to the home page but i was unable to do so. it just wouldn't show on the view.

After a while I let it go and just kept going. (and forgot about the css file of the home page)

Now i am deploying the website on a windows server and sundelly the css file is visable on the page and looks like this:

[image: Server site:]

I checked it locally but the css was still not visible here. Locally the page lookes like this (its dutch):

[image]

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welkom</h1>
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml.css:**

```
body {
}

h1 {
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I also tryed adding this to **_Layout.cshtml** but it did not work:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

**Update:**

Just noticed that the footer also appears to be much larger on the server but i dont have a separate css file for the footer:

**Local:**
[image: Local:]
**Server:**
[image: Server]

Comment: If you click F12,can you see any error in Console？

Comment: No errors unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

You have used the scoped CSS file (Index.cshtml.css) to declare your style instead of the standard CSS file found in wwwroot/css. The bundled CSS file that gets generated from all your scoped CSS files is named using the following format: `nameof(your_assembly).styles.css`. So if your app is named WebApplication1, you reference the generated file in your layout like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@(nameof(WebApplication1)).styles.css" />
```

See more here: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/355/css-isolation-in-razor-pages

Comment: i've added this to _Layout in <head> but it's not working for some reason? Do i need to leave <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> in? And why is it working on server and not my pc?\